# javascript: Extened destroy method doesn't get called but super does get called

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

Why isn't my destroy method in my extended class get called but my super destroy method does? And could you get my example to work that way please;

```js
function MyClass(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  
  this.destroy = function() {
    console.log('Super Class Destroy Method');
  }
  
  if(age == undefined) {
    return null;
  }
  
  return new MyClass2(name, age);
}

class MyClass2 extends MyClass {
  
  constructor(...args) {
    super(args[0]);
    
    this.age = args[1];
  }
  
  destroy() {
    super.destroy();
    
    console.log('Extedned Destroy Method');
  }
}


var myObj = MyClass('John Doe', 9);

myObj.destroy();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parent class, in the constructor, you do:

```
  this.destroy = function() {
    console.log('Super Class Destroy Method');
  }
```

This puts the destroy method *directly on the instance*. In contrast, in the child class:

```
  destroy() {
    super.destroy();
    
    console.log('Extedned Destroy Method');
  }
```

This `destroy` method is on the *prototype*.

This is what the prototype chain looks like, for a child instance:

```
instance <- MyClass2.prototype <- MyClass.prototype <- Object.prototype
```

If you instantiate a child, the parent's constructor will assign to a property of the instance when you do `this.destroy =`, so `super.destroy()` won't work (the superclass has no `destroy` method on its prototype).

So, change the superclass `destroy` to an actual method on the prototype.

```js
function MyClass(name, age) {
  this.name = name;

  if (age == undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  return new MyClass2(name, age);
}
MyClass.prototype.destroy = function() {
  console.log('Super Class Destroy Method');
}

class MyClass2 extends MyClass {

  constructor(...args) {
    super(args[0]);

    this.age = args[1];
  }

  destroy() {
    super.destroy();

    console.log('Extedned Destroy Method');
  }
}


var myObj = new MyClass('John Doe', 9);

myObj.destroy();
```

Though, it's pretty odd to use both `function` and `class` syntax together, consider using just `class` instead:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    return age === undefined ? null : new Child(name, age);
  }
  destroy() {
    console.log('Super Class Destroy Method');
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(args[0]);
    this.age = args[1];
  }
  destroy() {
    super.destroy();
    console.log('Extedned Destroy Method');
  }
}

var myObj = new Parent('John Doe', 9);
myObj.destroy();
```

Also, the `return null` in case no `age` is passed doesn't work because when you call a function with `new`, an object *will* be returned regardless; `return null` will still return an instance of the parent. Consider calling a function to create the object, not a constructor, before verification - or, throw an error if the argument is invalid:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === Parent.prototype) {
      // avoid stack overflow
      return new Child(name, age);
    }
  }
  destroy() {
    console.log('Super Class Destroy Method');
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(args[0]);
    this.age = args[1];
  }
  destroy() {
    super.destroy();
    console.log('Extedned Destroy Method');
  }
}

const makeParent = (name, age) => age === undefined ? null : new Parent(name, age);
const myObj = makeParent('John Doe', 9);
myObj.destroy();
```

Comment: The reason I built it like that was to return null if the age parameter wasn't there so I didn't use the new keyword, can you refractor your code to be like mine and return null if that parameter isn't there

Comment: I tested your code and it doesn't return null if age isn't present

Comment: Oh, I see, the `return null` (in both of our codes) isn't working at all because you're invoking with `new`, which must return an object. Either don't call the function with `new`, or return an empty object instead

Comment: Your example works but I still end up doubling my code just because of the destroy method, what I mean is that I could return null in the constructor of just a simple class function without using the new keyword and then calling the extended class but the destory method is the problem when I want to return null. Do you see what I mean. Can you make an aleternative

Comment: What does the `destroy` method actually do? It seems quite odd for it to be needed for every subclass - just put it on the parent class alone, is what I'd do, if feasible. The `makeParent` factory function that might return `null` is completely separate

Comment: It's just an example of using super class and extended class, it could be an init function for actual purposes.

Comment: If each subclass needs a different init function, then it makes sense to duplicate it on each subclass since the logic is different. If they're all the same, then only define it in one place, on the parent class.